# php - Escape php variables in exec()

Tags: php

Morning guys,

Am having trouble escaping a string with variables that I want to pass to exec(). Here is the string:

```
$send_telemetry = exec ( 'echo "Temp 1="'.$temp_1[0].'" Pressure 1="'.$pressure_1[0].'" Flow 1 ="'.$flow_1[0].'" | mutt -s "Telemetry values for AREA 11C" telemetry@mymail.com' ) ;
echo "$send_telemetry" ;
```

I had this working before, but some over eager newbie technician thought it a smart idea to change the code and he ended up making a mess out of it. I am aware of `shell_exec()` but I prefer `exec()`.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the PHP website about the function `escapeshellarg`

> escapeshellarg() adds single quotes around a string and quotes/escapes
>   any existing single quotes allowing you to pass a string directly to a
>   shell function and having it be treated as a single safe argument.
>   This function should be used to escape individual arguments to shell
>   functions coming from user input. The shell functions include exec(),
>   system() and the backtick operator.

So what you should probably be doing is escaping any variables that you are passing into your command, like so...

```
$send_telemetry = exec ( 'echo "Temp 1=" ' . escapeshellarg($temp_1[0]) . ' "Pressure 1=" ' . escapeshellarg($pressure_1[0]) . ' "Flow 1 =" ' . escapeshellarg($flow_1[0]) . ' " | mutt -s "Telemetry values for AREA 11C" telemetry@mymail.com' ) ;
echo "$send_telemetry" ;
```